# Why can't an anonymous user see the xhprof link at the bottom if permission is set?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I set the permissions so that anonymous users can see xhprof but I can't seem to see the link at the bottom of the page when the page loads.  I am able to view the page /admin/reports/xhprof/ as anonymous but just can't get the link to appear. I am sure it isn't hidden because I can't find it in Firebug.

I tried flushing the cache and running cron but still no luck.

I added a print_r to the following part of the xhprof code and I get some weird character response. So it leads me to believe that it is a problem somewhere with drupal_register_shutdown_function.

```
function xhprof_boot() {
  // Initialize XHProf.
  if (xhprof_xhprof_enable()) {
    print_r(drupal_register_shutdown_function('xhprof_shutdown'));
  }
}
```

I get a response of weird characters:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [callback] => xhprof_shutdown [arguments] => Array ( ) ) )
����r�H�0xmE�;T��mI� <��d�=�N�[��d�n�F(��@@It��{���#���ͣ̓lfU�D$(QRwR�%�CfVVVfVV֫����?�쐞
�7�ɻ��[$� ��Ba�|�|xs~x����]JJ�b��s�#��������u�����n�:��l�Q���G�P���<-�
.....
.....
Fatal error: Call to undefined function drupal_get_path_alias() in 
.../includes/common.inc on line 2250
```

Weird thing is I do have an older database of my site and the problem doesn't happen. Only happens on my production database copy of my site.

I tried commenting out every function that calls drupal_register_shutdown_function or register_shutdown_function but I can't seem to find what is causing the problem on my site.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my issue by going to Configuration -> Development and unchecking "Compress cached pages". This way I able to clear the cache and view the page as anonymous and see the link.

If I try to view the page the second time (since it is cached). I get this error below: Fatal error: Call to undefined function url() in .../sites/all/modules/xhprof/xhprof.module on line 190.  I think that the xhprof was just meant to be viewed on on uncached pages.